# Recursive CTE to generate all combinations sub groups within a group

Tags: common-table-expression, window-functions, recursive-query, mariadb-10.5

I am trying produce an aggregated result for all possible combinations of rows linked by one column (package_id) but where another column (package_item_id) does not match.

I have a derived table packages:

| package_id | package_item_id | quantity | variant_id | retail_price | sell_price | stock_available |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1000001 | 28 | 1 | 3399 | 489.00 | 342.30 | 26 |
| 1000001 | 28 | 1 | 3400 | 489.00 | 342.30 | 23 |
| 1000001 | 28 | 1 | 3409 | 489.00 | 342.30 | 81 |
| 1000001 | 29 | 1 | 821 | 44.95 | 35.95 | 741 |
| 1000001 | 30 | 1 | 807 | 39.95 | 31.95 | 162 |
| 1000002 | 31 | 1 | 6369 | 519.00 | 363.30 | 93 |
| 1000002 | 31 | 1 | 6371 | 519.00 | 363.30 | 60 |
| 1000002 | 31 | 1 | 6372 | 519.00 | 363.30 | 40 |
| 1000002 | 31 | 1 | 19289 | 519.00 | 363.30 | 24 |
| 1000002 | 31 | 1 | 19290 | 519.00 | 363.30 | 20 |
| 1000002 | 31 | 1 | 21774 | 519.00 | 363.30 | 14 |
| 1000002 | 31 | 1 | 23045 | 519.00 | 363.30 | 0 |
| 1000002 | 37 | 1 | 821 | 44.95 | 35.95 | 741 |
| 1000002 | 38 | 1 | 807 | 39.95 | 31.95 | 162 |

This structure supports a package deal system for a retail website:

package_id relates to a group of elements that can be purchased as package.

package_item_id breaks down the sub elements (of varying number depending on the package) where the user may have a choice of variant_ids to select from.

i.e. Package: Premium Mountain Bike, Package Item: Frame, Variants: Blue,Red,Yellow, Package Item: Wheels, Variants: Narrow, Wide, Package Item: Saddle, Variants: Standard

I am trying to produce a result which aggregates every potential combination for a package_id. Concatenating the package_id & variants_ids into a querystring and calculating the total prices for grouped items. The quantity column determines the amount supplied for package_item_id so is a multiplier for the prices. Furthermore I would like to check there is sufficient stock of each variant to make up the package true (1) or false (0)

An example of the result I am trying to achieve for just the first package_id:

| package_id | querystring | retail_price | sell_price | in_stock |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1000001 | `p_id=1000001&v_id=3399&v_id=819&v_id=807` | 598.9 | 430.2 | 1 |
| 1000001 | `p_id=1000001&v_id=3400&v_id=819&v_id=807` | 598.9 | 430.2 | 1 |
| 1000001 | `p_id=1000001&v_id=3409&v_id=819&v_id=807` | 598.9 | 430.2 | 1 |
| 1000001 | `p_id=1000001&v_id=3399&v_id=821&v_id=807` | 573.9 | 410.2 | 1 |
| 1000001 | `p_id=1000001&v_id=3400&v_id=821&v_id=807` | 573.9 | 410.2 | 1 |
| 1000001 | `p_id=1000001&v_id=3409&v_id=821&v_id=807` | 573.9 | 410.2 | 1 |

I have been attempting to use window functions in combination recursive CTE to create all different combinations under combination ID which I was hoping to them group to get the aggerated result I need but so far I can't achieve what I am aiming to do.

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE cte_packages AS (
SELECT 
  package_id,
  DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY package_id) AS p_group,
  package_item_id,
  DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY package_id ORDER BY package_item_id) AS pi_group,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY package_item_id ORDER BY variant_id) AS pi_group_row,
  COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY package_item_id) AS pi_group_row_count,
  quantity,
  variant_id,
  retail_price,
  sell_price,
  stock_available
FROM packages
),
cte_combinations AS
(
  SELECT 
        0 AS combination_id,
        p_group,
        p_group AS next_p_group,
        pi_group,
        pi_group_row,
        CASE 
          WHEN pi_group_row < pi_group_row_count
          THEN pi_group_row + 1
          ELSE 1
        END
        AS next_pi_group_row,
        pi_group_row_count,
        package_id,
        package_item_id,
        quantity,
        variant_id,
        retail_price,
        sell_price,
        stock_available     
    FROM 
        cte_packages
    WHERE 
        p_group = 1 AND pi_group = 1 AND pi_group_row = 1
    UNION
    SELECT
        cc.combination_id + 1,
        cpi.p_group,
        CASE 
          WHEN cpi.pi_group_row = cpi.pi_group_row_count
          THEN cpi.p_group + 1
          ELSE cpi.p_group
        END
        AS next_p_group,
        cpi.pi_group,
        cpi.pi_group_row,
        CASE 
          WHEN cpi.pi_group_row < cpi.pi_group_row_count
          THEN cpi.pi_group_row + 1
          ELSE 1
        END
        AS next_pi_group_row,
        cpi.pi_group_row_count,
        cpi.package_id,
        cpi.package_item_id,
        cpi.quantity,
        cpi.variant_id,
        cpi.retail_price,
        cpi.sell_price,
        cpi.stock_available
    FROM
        cte_combinations cc
    INNER JOIN
        cte_packages cpi
        ON cpi.p_group = cc.next_p_group AND cpi.pi_group = 1 AND cpi.pi_group_row = cc.next_pi_group_row
    LEFT JOIN
        cte_packages opi
        ON opi.p_group = cpi.p_group AND opi.pi_group <> 1
)
SELECT * FROM cte_combinations
```

I am not sure if I am approaching this correctly or is what I'm trying to achieve is possible.

DB Fiddle link below:

https://dbfiddle.uk/hEXZa674

Comment: probably someone disliked your question cause of hosting content as an image in a different site, I would recommend that you paste the image directly on stack overflow [some people once they get an answer they remove the remote content]

Comment: Unfortunately its not possible 'You need at least 10 reputation to post images'.

Comment: Hi - what people dislike is images in general - mainly because it is not possible to copy the information they contain if you want to try out a solution. Please add all relevant information to your question as editable text. Format code as code and data as tables - include enough source data to show all relevant use cases, the SQL you've managed to write and the result you want to achieve. While dbfiddles can be useful additional help, they are not a substitute for including this information in your question

Comment: Thanks for the tips. Normally I can find solutions I need from searching stackoverflow so this is only my 2nd question.

Answer (score -1):

AFAICT we need to generate all possible combinations of `variant_id` for each `package_id`. Since the number of `package_item_id` varies, this will involve a self-join for each `package_item_id`. However, with varying numbers of items, one would typically need a dynamic number of joins, which SQL does not natively support.

This snippet would probably achieve the result you're looking for but **only** for three `package_item_id` values per `package_id`

```sql
SELECT 
  p1.package_id,
  CONCAT('p_id=', p1.package_id, '&v_id=', p1.variant_id, 
         '&v_id=', p2.variant_id, '&v_id=', p3.variant_id) AS querystring,
  (p1.quantity * p1.retail_price + p2.quantity * p2.retail_price + p3.quantity * p3.retail_price) AS total_retail_price,
  (p1.quantity * p1.sell_price + p2.quantity * p2.sell_price + p3.quantity * p3.sell_price) AS total_sell_price,
  CASE 
    WHEN p1.stock_available >= p1.quantity AND p2.stock_available >= p2.quantity AND p3.stock_available >= p3.quantity 
    THEN 1 
    ELSE 0 
  END AS stock_available
FROM packages p1
JOIN packages p2 ON p1.package_id = p2.package_id AND p1.package_item_id <> p2.package_item_id
JOIN packages p3 ON p1.package_id = p3.package_id AND p1.package_item_id <> p3.package_item_id AND p2.package_item_id <> p3.package_item_id
GROUP BY p1.package_id, p1.variant_id, p2.variant_id, p3.variant_id;
```

Comment: Thanks weshouman. This works perfectly for up to the package_items but unfortunately the number of package items does vary. My example data was simplified.

Comment: I am still hopeful there might be a solution using a recursive query & window functions on the original table to provide a sequential number pattern to step through during the recursion. So far I am failing but hopefully I can get close enough I can update the question so others can help me over the line.

Comment: I think I am about ready to give up on my attempts at a recursive CTE query. I was just looking again at your example. Looking at the the real production data it appears there is currently no package with more than 5 package items but there there a many variation between 2 to 5 items. I was hoping I could adjust your example to support 2-5 package items?

Comment: I also just notice that the same package items repeat themselves in different orders. Is there a way to avoid that?